# ExpressRoute - maximum number of connected VNets allowed

Tags: azure, azure-networking

Say for example that I have an Azure Enterprise agreement and within that I create two subscriptions - Dev and Test.

Is my understanding correct, that:

Within my Dev subscription, I could create an ExpressRoute circuit and connect up to 10 VNets. I could then do the same in the Test subscription. So in total across Dev and Test I would have 20 separate VNets that can be reached by my on-prem resources (assuming the standard edition of ExpressRoute)?

I am basing this on the documentation here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-faqs

My assumption, is that like everything else in Azure, that the limits are per subscription (and not across all subscriptions in the Enterprise agreement, but for the sake of sanity I would just like to double check!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My assumption, is that like everything else in Azure, that the limits
>   are per subscription (and not across all subscriptions in the
>   Enterprise agreement.

You are right, the limits are per subscription.
We can via Azure Portal to check the useage:
Subscription-->Usage+quptsa
[image]

Comment: Does this helpful? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.